# How do you view a Polymer element's demo page in Polymer Start Kit?

Tags: polymer, gulp, bower, web-component, polymer-starter-kit

After doing:

```
cd polymer-starter-kit-1.0.3
npm install -g gulp bower && npm install && bower install
gulp serve
```

How do you browse to and view an element's demo page, such as:

```
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/paper-input/demo/
```

When viewing the source of the URL above, it shows the paths to be relative to the demo directory, in the form of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
```

What do you need to do to make the paths resolve properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `index.html` at the end of the URL.

`http://localhost:3000/bower_components/paper-input/demo/index.html`

Comment: Yes, indeed. Where is this documented and/or why does it work that way?

Comment: I did not find any documentation about this, I just tried it out in my browser. Your original URL points to a directory not to a file. I guess the webserver is not configured to serve index.html by default for all directories.